# How can I fetch/print the path or url of an entity reference to my twig template (Drupal 8)?

Tags: php, drupal, twig, theming

I have been trying to figure out how I can pull the url of a node content type using an entity reference.

[image]

Apparently using `{{ links.entity.uri }}` or `{{ links.entity.url }}` does not work

```
<div>

{% for links in node.field_related_items %}

    <h2>{{ links.entity.label }}</h2>
    <a href="{{ links.entity.uri }} " ></a>

{% endfor %}

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<a href="{{ links.entity.id }}"></a>
```

This will only take you to `/node/entity_id` though and not `/entity_name/entity_id`

I would like to expand upon this answer by saying that you should add a `Drupal::entityQuery()` to your `.theme` file. Inside of this query, you'll want to grab the "alias" which is the link to the content. In your case this will give you these links `/migrations` and `/aboutiom`.

Here's an example of what that might look like...

```
  function theme_name_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                  ->condition('status', 1)
                  ->condition('type', 'related_links')
    $nids = $query->execute();
    $nodes =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
    $related_links = [];
    foreach ($nodes as $item) {
      $alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'.$item->id());
      $related_links[] = [
        'title' => $item->getTitle(),
        'id' => $item->id(),
        'field' => $item->get('field_name')->value,
        'alias' => $alias,
      ];
    }
    $variables['related_links'] = $related_links;
  }
```

Now in your twig template you can do something like this...

```
{% for link in related_links %}
    <a href="{{ link['alias'] }}">{{ link['title'] }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```